# Writhe vs wriggle

Tags: meaning

Are these words interchangeable?
For instance if I see someone in pain on the ground or in a chair twisting their body because they have been poisoned or someone who has been shot 
Is he wriggling/writhing?

Comment: What is "**the** have been poisoned" above? It can be both "wriggle" and "writhe". I think "writhe" is a better choice, but I believe it can be both.

Comment: writhing is associated with pain; wriggling is not. Babies can wriggle. Bad guys on the ground writhe [often in pain].

Comment: Well, I agree "writhe" is better, but "wriggle" also has a definition "to writhe; squirm; twist to and fro" on dictionary.com. The etymologies of "writhe" and "wriggle" are related and are cognates of "wry" and "wreath", which also relate to "wriggle" and "writhe".

Answer (score 1):

One difference: *wriggle out of X* is idiomatic, e.g. a cat might try to wriggle out of a blanket it is wrapped in.  *Writhe out of X* doesn't work.

Wriggling usually implies you are trapped and trying to break free by twisting around.  You might wriggle out of tight clothes, a tight space, a wrestling move, etc.  It can also suggest small, somewhat quick back and forth twisting motions, like in dancing.

*Writhe* is more about moving like a snake/worm/insect/etc., it suggests slower, longer movements.  There's also more of a implication or connotation of pain or torture, or other negativity, by default with *writhe* than *wriggle*.

If pain or injury is involved *writhe* is usually the word you want to use.  *Writhing in pain* is also idiomatic, *wriggling in pain* is not.